# Parsing html datetime-local type input into java LocalDateTime

Tags: java, jsp, datetime

> Code

```
JSP:

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <fmt:formatDate value="${sighting.sightingDateAsDate}" var="sightingDateString" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"/>
    <sf:input type="datetime-local" class="add-form form-control" path="sightingDate" value="${sightingDateString}"/>
</div>

Controller:

String sightingDateString = request.getParameter("sightingDate");
LocalDateTime sightingDate = LocalDateTime.parse(sightingDateString.replace("T"," "), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

I'm working on this edit form.  fmt:formatDate is to convert sightingDate  into a format that is readable by html so the input field datetime-local would be populated with existing LocalDateTime value.

Now the problem is converting it back to LocalDateTime.
The current error I'm getting is :

> Error

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is 
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-03-22 01:00' could not be parsed at index 10
```

I also tried without the replace("T"," ").  The error will say Text '2017-03-22T01:00' instead of Text '2017-03-22 01:00'

Comment: The `ISO_DATE_TIME` format has the `T` in there, so it seems to me you are breaking things by replacing your `T` with a space.

Comment: I have no problem parsing `2017-03-22T01:00` using `LocalDateTime.parse(sightingDateString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);`. I suppose your issue is somewhere else. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: In your JSP, in `pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"`, should those be capital `H`s (`HH:mm:ss`)?

Answer (score 6):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(sightingDateString);
```

Thanks